Warn log from ISH when different domain
I have a problem with warn logs produce by ISH during a job.
This job needs to create URL for customers in their own domain.

com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.url.URLPipelineAction  - URL points to different domain (xxxx-FR-Site, current domain is: xxxx-Site). Using default AppURLID '-

I did some research I saw this topic on : Intershop topic
It says that there is a fix on the v11 but we won't upgrade ISH version for a while. Is there a workaround please ?
Thanks for your help.
